# Изменение оформления по нажатию на текст

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия по тексту класса mesg менялось обормление текста?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .mesg {
                padding:10px;
                color:#000;
                background-color:#fff;
            }
            .mesg:focus {
                background-color:#00F;
            }
        </style>
        <title>бла</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-left:30%;">
            <p style="width:550px; font-size:14px; text-indent:20px;" class="mesg">
                <kf ,kf ,kf ,fk ,fk ,fk ,kf ,kf ,kf ,kf ,kf ,kf</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.mesg').click(function() {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
```

Comment: Это ведь jquery?

Comment: Да, именно он :-)

Comment: А решение на javascript не можете подсказать? :-)

Comment: Какую именно библиотеку?

Comment: а что мешает подключить библиотеку?...

Comment: Например, вот эту - [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js). А вообще любую свежую версию.

Comment: Какую именно использовать? У jQuery много библиотек!

Comment: jQuery - это и есть библиотека!

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с дивами, а как все теги перебрать, погуглите:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i].className == 'mesg') {
        all[i].onclick = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        }
    }
}
```